# How to make text field "become first responder" in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uialertview

I have two text fields in a UIAlertView. I want the second one to become the first responder so that the user doesn't have to tap on it. After I show the alert view, I have this code:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

The only problem is that it does not work. The first text field has the typer in it. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this same problem with trying to set focus to the password field in the UIAlertView (I was pre-populating the username). I had to use the delegate method:

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

If I tried it on willPresentAlertView or when I create the alertView, it didn't work, only on didPresentAlertView. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for a `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` AlertView style. Only wish that I didn't see it change fields. Tried this in the willPresent though and it would not acknowledge the field.

Comment: I tried this in didPresentAlertView but it did not work.

Comment: It may be different now, the UIAlertViews have been changed to presentation views in iOS8.

Comment: Note that in the solution above it looks for a textFieldAtIndex:1.

To be safe I recommend you first test that the textfield exists at index 1 before you execute the code above.

Finally you are probably going to be testing for textFieldAtIndex:0

Comment: Similarly, I have an alertView that I added several textfields to. I just assigned the first textfield to a property to set it as the firstResponder in this delegate method. Also, it still does work in since iOS8; confirmed in 10 and 11. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an alert and add a UITextField to it. You can then assign the new textfield as your first responder and that will bring up the keyboard with your alert.

Here is a story that might be what you are looking for.

[Alert View with Prompt](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html)

Answer (score 0):

The tagged answer is correct, I am just adding a bit more clarification which is related to my comment above, here is the code to; test that the field exists before you use it and looks at index 0:

```
    if ([alertView textFieldAtIndex:0])
    {
        UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```